# Featherlight Plugin Better Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

I have this code:

```
<section data-featherlight-gallery="" data-feather-filter="a">
  <a class="apt-gallery-d" href="img.png">
    <img class="module-img-size" src="img.png" alt="1 Alcoba">
  </a>
  <a class="apt-gallery-d hidden" href="img.png">
    <img class="module-img-size" src="img.png" alt="1 Alcoba">
  </a>
</section>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('a.apt-gallery-d').featherlightGallery({
      openSpeed: 300,
      previousIcon: ' ',
      nextIcon: ' ',
      variant: 'custom-lightbox-css',
      loading: 'Cargando...',
  });
})
```

When the lightbox opens, a slider appears with the default lightbox navigation, however the navigation isn't very user friendly. You don't know when you've seen the last image because it looks like and endless loop. Also, if I have only one image the navigation appears regardless.

How can I better control when this next prev arrows show up?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc:

> It sets the classes `'featherlight-first-slide'` and `'featherlight-last-slide'` if the current slide is the first and/or last one.

You can use those to customize the look or disable the previous & next buttons as you wish

Comment: Nice, gonna play with those and will let you know! Thanks I really appreciate it.